# Why does Vaseegaran use the word "dot" for "agree"?

Tags: dialogue, 2.0

In the Indian movie *2.0*, Vaseegaran uses the word "dot" for agreeing to things. Why does he use the word "dot" for "agree"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The word "Dot", apart from being a catch-phrase, is the Chitti (a robot's) way of saying "Period".** It roughly translates to him **agreeing/affirming to a statement** or a work or anything else. You could also think of it as a 'Tech-y way' of saying "Yes", "Sure" or "Ok?"

Comment: Vaseegaran uses dot often in Robot and 2.0 as well. Watch the movie again. It is his catchphrase.

Comment: Oh ! i always thought it was only used by Chitti.. ill rewatch it - thank you for letting me know!